# Facebook Credits API: refunding creates a new order id?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-credits

When I refund a specific order ID using the updateOrder() API, it correctly updates this order's status to 'refunded' as expected but also creates an entirely new order id also with a status of 'refunded'.  This makes it look like a user has been refunded twice as much as they spent ... anyone know why this is?  Or if it's documented anywhere in Facebook's amazing API docs?